# Difference between Codec and Parser in LibAV

Tags: libavcodec, libav

I am following this link to figure out decoding using libAV library. In the `decode` function, it declares a `codec` and a `parser`.

```
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
parser = av_parser_init(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```

What is the difference between the two >

Answer (score 1):

The parser takes a stream of bytes and turns it into a representation in memory, but does not convert the bytes to pixeles. The parser can read things like resolution, encoding parameters, where frames begin and end, etc.